# How to capture shell script program output from cucumber/aruba?

Tags: ruby, bash, shell, cucumber, aruba

I want to capture output which I'm running from the cucumber feature file.

I created one shell script program and placed it in /usr/local/bin/ so it can be accessible from anywhere in system.

**abc_qa.sh -**

```
arg=$1
if [[ $arg = 1 ]]
then
    echo $(date)
fi
```

**project structure of cucumber -**

aruba -

.

├── features

│ ├── support

│   │   └── env.rb

│   └── use_aruba_cucumber.feature

├── Gemfile

**Gemfile -**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'aruba', '~> 0.14.2'
```

**env.rb -**

```
require 'aruba/cucumber'
```

**use_aruba_cucumber.feature -**

```
Feature: Cucumber
 Scenario: First Run
    When I run `bash abc_qa.sh 1`
```

I want to capture this abc_qa.sh program output in the cucumber itself and compare this date is right or wrong by using any kind of simple test and make this test as a pass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `%x(command)` to get the stdout of your command.

You can then use [Time.parse](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/time/rdoc/Time.html#method-c-parse) to convert `"Sat Nov 5 12:04:18 CET 2016"` to `2016-11-05 12:04:18 +0100` as Time object, and compare it to Time.now :

```
require 'time'
time_from_abc_script = Time.parse(%x(bash abc_qa.sh 1))
puts (Time.now-time_from_abc_script).abs < 5 # No more than 5s difference between 2 times
```

You could use this boolean in any test file you want.

For example :

In `features/use_aruba_with_cucumber.feature` :

```
Feature: Cucumber
 Scenario: First Run
  When I run `bash abc_qa.sh 1`
  Then the output should be the current time
```

and `features/step_definitions/time_steps.rb` :

```
require 'time'

Then(/^the output should be the current time$/) do
  time_from_script = Time.parse(last_command_started.output)
  expect(time_from_script).to be_within(5).of(Time.now)
end
```

Comment: I'm new to cucumber. can you please tell me In which what I need to write and in what manner?

Comment: I'll install aruba/cucumber on my machine and write a feature and step definition.

Comment: @EricDuminil- Fantastic. one more thing, output of shell script contains : Sat Nov 5 19:30:03 IST 2016. I want to check its day is in seven days of week then pass this test. How I can do that?

Comment: It could probably be another question. If this one is answered, please consider upvoting and accepting my answer. I'm not sure I understand what you want. Do you want to check that "Sat" is the abbreviation of a day of the week?

Comment: see [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40436724/how-to-compare-date-in-cucumber-aruba] question for better understanding and answer if you got it.